# Google-plus API, plus.login scope, not able to access G+ Moments, whats wrong?

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-plus, google-plus-signin

My scope is set to : https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login

I know I am using the scope because when I change it, and for example add the email scope, the permissions requested change, and if I add an invalid scope, I get an error saying that my other scope(s) including the above mentioned are valid. So I am for sure using this scope.

On the G+ oauth API reference it says this scope should allow me to access Moments.

These are the permissions requested:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/klaNa.png

My oauth app/client on google developers dash is using the google plus API. I am able to get a token, and name/email when using certain scopes. This is for a web server application.

I also turned off the security settings for "trusted applications" on my test account.

Comment: You need to provide more information about the API method you are using, how you are calling it, and what errors you are getting.

Comment: This doesn't have to do with calling the API, I don't have a problem with that. My problem is with the scope not getting the right permissions. The permissions requested do not include access to write new moments, as you can see. Yet I am definitely using the correct scope to generate the oauth token. So this problem is before I even generate the token, And I cannot see how it could be a problem on my end, given that the scope is the only variable in question and is set correctly. I am thinking perhaps google has a security feature that is blocking me, or a app review process like facebook

Comment: But I cannot find that stuff, and I have turned of the optional security on my test account already

Comment: You are jumping to conclusions as to the problem but you don't provide enough info for us to validate that. The exact endpoints being called are very important when debugging scope issues.

Comment: I should have mentioned I am using the passportjs node.js module, not a raw ouath request. Now I am trying to figure out how to print the authentication URL of the requests it sends to post here using a custom callback function (I already tried middleware), but anyways - since passport handles that for me, correct me if I am wrong but the only variable which I change before authentication, to my knowledge, is the scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have not added request_visible_actions parameters to your authorization request.

Please validate that correct authorization request should be like this,

*https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?**request_visible_actions=http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity**&access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=&redirect_uri=&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login*

Comment: Yeah that's it, thanks. My Oauth software does not support it so I will have to find a work around.